# How to let your app take data from apps that are already installed by Android

Tags: java, android, share

I want to make an app that takes info/data from other apps that are already installed on my phone ( Android ). By example: Let's say I want to make an app that shows how many messages I sent to each person with my phone. Then I would like to get my app linked with the message app on my phone and count how many times I sent someone a message , get that data, and put it on my app. 
When I search for this problem, one 'solution' I found was working with intents, but it's NOT that, by far as I know, you can use intents to share data between apps you created yourself. I want to be able to get data from apps that I did not make. HOW? Thanks already

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, otherwise it would be a security issue, think about a bank app... In Android all the apps are fisically separated into different directories.

You can access data only from apps that expose methods, like Intent.